# How to remove a string from file in mac terminal

Tags: macos, shell, unix, terminal

I have a file with million records and each line ends with `SYSTEM;\N`.

I want to delete all occurrences of `;\N` from file. How can I approach this?

Comment: Please show 3-4 lines of your file and also the code you have tried.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the sed command to replace all the occurrences of the ';\N' from the file and replace it with ''.

```
sed -i 's/original/new/g' file.txt
```

Explanation:

sed = Stream EDitor

-i = in-place (i.e. save back to the original file)

The command string:
s = the substitute command

original = a regular expression describing the word to replace (or just the word itself)

new = the text to replace it with

g = global (i.e. replace all and not just the first occurrence)

file.txt = the file name

Comment: sed -i  's/;\N//g' test112.csv  is not working on terminal

Answer (score 1):

This worked finally `sed -i '' 's/;\\N//g' test112.csv`

Comment: Using `-i` seems like a terrible idea.  sed is going to write your data into a temporary file, so if disk space is a concern, this doesn't avoid that problem.  If you do run out of disk, will using `-i` cause some data to be truncated?  Just do `sed 's/;\\N/g' test112.csv > test112.out`.  Then make sure it worked.  Then do `mv test112.out test112.csv`.